# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' in GitHub Actions

Tags: python, pandas, github, github-actions

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but github actions are new to me. I'm having trouble understanding this error for my this github action to simply run my script at regular cadence. I receive this notification:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/review_reports/review_reports/review_reports.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I have checked my python and pip in my terminal, which are both running on conda are are version 3.x (python is 3.9.7). My pandas version that I checked in my original Jupyter Notebook (from where I downloaded the .py file) is 1.3.4.

I've already tried the solutions in this (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11604) but the issue still persists.

Please let me know how I can resolve the issue. Thank you!

Here is my yml file:

```
name: run_script
on: 
    schedule:
      - cron: "8 0 * * *" #runs at 08:00 UTC everyday
jobs:
  run_review_reports:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9.7
      - name: execute py script
        run: |
          python review_reports.py
```

Comment: What does your Github Actions configuration file look like? Do you install pandas there first?

Comment: @MattDMo I added the yml file I'm using

Comment: Where is the **requirements.txt** file located? https://github.com/actions/setup-python#caching-packages-dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually need to **install python dependencies** (after the setup) before running your python script:

**Something like this (in an intermediary step for example):**

```yaml
      - name: Install Python dependencies
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip pandas
```

*Note: You will need to install all necessary dependencies that way, or use a requirements.txt file, or even a virtual environment for example.*

**If this is the only dependency your python script needs, your workflow could therefore look like this:**

```
name: run_script
on: 
    schedule:
      - cron: "8 0 * * *" #runs at 08:00 UTC everyday
jobs:
  run_review_reports:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repo content
        uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout the repository content to github runner.
      - name: setup python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9.7
      - name: Install Python dependencies
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip pandas
      - name: execute py script
        run: |
          python review_reports.py
```

- [Here is a similar workflow executing a python script as reference.](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/03-python-script-workflow.yml)